# Hide Products from customers and view only for retaillers

Tags: magento, permissions, magento-1.8, user-permissions

Need hep about **hiding new products from customers and view them only for retailers** group. simply new products can be viewed for some time only for retailers. **retailers can view all products** but normal **customer can view old products only**. I have searched web but I could only find ad-min privileges and giving retailers price. Using ***Magento 1.8***

Comment: You can try to get customer group and check if customer group is retailer then show new product else show old products.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?